# Why isn't prerender working on my site?

Tags: html, prerender

My site has a quiz, and after each question is answered, there is a 'next' link. Since most of the time the user will go to the next question, I'd like to prerender the page.

So I put this in the `<head>`

```
<link rel="prerender" href="/">
```

and this in the `<body>`

```
<a href="/">Next</a>
```

I tried it in Chrome and Firefox and it's not working. What could I be doing wrong?

I also tried putting the full address in the link

```
<link rel="prerender" href="https://example.com">
```

but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using XHMLHttpRequests. According to this doc: https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/prerender a XHML Post request will cancel the prerender and stop it from being swapped in.

I imagine this will be difficult to solve as the server will require the post data from the user before it can safely render the page. So, in this situation the prerended document will always be discarded and a new document will be rendered.

Comment: I know it's not working because it takes about 400ms to load with or with out the preload link. I'm using Chrome 54.0.2840.71.

Comment: Are you able to provide a snippet of your html?

Comment: You can visit the site: walawali.com. It's adding the link to the head with javascript right now (but still not working).

Comment: This is the header I currently see:

Comment: Ignore above comment... didn't realise you were using XHMLHttp Post method.